# set-cookie returned in response headers, cors origin is not wildcarded, but cookie is not stored in browser

Tags: express, cookies, google-cloud-platform, axios, cross-domain

This question has been asked a million times, but I've tried it all and nothing seems to work.

My situation:

I've deployed a node/express backend as a Google Cloud Run service.
I am running my frontend locally, trying to login to my backend in the cloud. Frontend is served on http, backend on https. I have enabled cors on the backend. My config is:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
}));
```

I am using `axios`, and I have set `withCredentials: true`:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = ApiURL;
const { data } = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `/api/login`,
    data: {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
        keepLoggedIn: this.state.keepLoggedIn,
    },
    withCredentials: true,
});
```

This setup works perfectly when I run my backend locally, but of course there is no cors then. When I try to log in when the frontend is pointed at the Cloud Run service, I get a response from the backend with a `set-cookie` header as expected, but no cookie ever appears in the Storage > Cookies section of the Chrome dev console as it does with my local backend. There is then of course nothing sent with the rest of my axios requests, which need the cookie.

I've been at this for a full day and its driving me nuts. I'm sure there is something simple I'm missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you update the question to be clear on exactly what you mean by *“but no cookie ever appears in the browser”*? What I mean, is can you be explicit about how you’re checking for the cookie? That is, are you looking at the storage section in browser devtools? Or are you instead somehow checking for the presence of the cookie from your frontend JavaScript code?

Comment: Done. By 'no cookie ever appears in the browser', I did indeed mean the cookie doesn't show in the chrome dev console. Let me know if the way I adjusted the question still seems unclear.

Comment: Thanks yes that makes it more clear